# BluePrism Java app: Error while spying the element Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa, java-access-bridge

> System.ApplicationException: Exception getting Java Identfier KeyBindings Exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at BluePrism.AMI.clsAMI.Spy(clsElementTypeInfo& elementType, List`1& identifiers)
>      at Automate.frmIntegrationAssistant.HandleSpyOrLaunchClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)

OS: Win 7 64 bit

My machine has installed below version of java

**jdk1.7.0_80**

**jre1.7.0_80**

**Java Access Bridge 2.0.2**

Target app compiled on:

**jdk1.7.0_80**

**Note:**
When I am doing spy at very first time I can able to get attributes without any problem. Error thrown when you do spy for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by following the below steps:

This solution will work for only 64-bit windows 7 or higher version of OS

1)Make sure you have installed jre 1.7 or higher version (1.7+ version will have JAB in build, so you don't need to install it externally)

2)Maker sure you have pasted below files under "Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate"

- JavaAccessBridge-64.dll
- JAWTAccessBridge-64.dll
- WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll

3) Enable JAB from windows control panel.

Now try to spy any java application. It should be working. Cheers!! :)